# File Reading in C, Random Error

Tags: c

Thank you everybody so far for your input and advice!

**Additionally:**

After testing and toying further, it seems individual calls to FileReader succeed. But calling FileReader multiple times (these might be separate versions of FileReader) causes the issue to occur.

**End Add**

Hello,

I have a very unusual problem [please read this fully: it's important] (Code::Blocks compiler, Windows Vista Home) [no replicable code] with the C File Reading functions (fread, fgetc). Now, normally, the File Reading functions load up the data correctly to a self-allocating and self-deallocating string (and it's not the string's issue), but this is where it gets bizarre (and where Quantum Physics fits in):

An error catching statement reports that EOF occurred too early (IE inside the comments section at the start of the text file it's loading). Printing out the string [after it's loaded] reports that indeed, it's too short (24 chars) (but it has enough space to fit it [~400] and no allocation issues). The fgetc loop iterator reports it's terminating at just 24 (the file is roughly 300 chars long) with an EOF: **This is where it goes whacky**:

Temporarily checking Read->_base reports the entire (~300) chars are loaded - no EOF at 24. Perplexed, [given it's an fgetc loop] I added a printf to display each char [as a %d so I could spot the -1 EOF] at every step so I could see what it was doing, and modified it so it was a single char. It loops fine, reaching the ~300 mark instead of 24 - but freezes up randomly moments later. BUT, when I removed printf, it terminated at 24 again and got caught by the error-catching statement.

**Summary**:
So, basically: I have a bug that is affected by the 'Observer Effect' out of quantum physics: When I try to observe the chars I get from fgetc via printf, the problem (early EOF termination at 24) disappears, but when I stop viewing it, the error-catch statement reports early termination.

The more bizarre thing is, this isn't the first time it's occurred. Fread had a similar problem, and I was unable to figure out why, and replaced it with the fgetc loop.

[Code can't really be supplied as the code base is 5 headers in size].

Snippet:

```
int X = 0; 
int C = 0; 
int I = 0;

while(Copy.Array[X] != EOF)
{
    //Copy.Array[X] = fgetc(Read);
    C = fgetc(Read);
    Copy.Array[X] = C;
    printf("%d %c\n",C,C); //Remove/add this as necessary
    if(C == EOF){break;}
    X++;
}
```

Side-Note: Breaking it down into the simplest format does not reproduce the error.

Comment: What you call "Quantum Physics Effects" is common in programming, when problems go away or change when you try to debug them, or when they only happen intermittently (known as phase-of-the-moon problems). Sometimes they go away of you sacrifice to the gods of engineering. So you'll need to supply some code anyway, or no-one will be able to help you.

Comment: (Why did you try to turn English into LISP?) This is not unusual in any way. It's usual enough to have a name: it's a [heisenbug](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/heisenbug.html).

Comment: Technically what you describe is called a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug) :)

Comment: I can do Lennart, but it consists of 5 headers, and there's no easy replication. I'll add a [probably unhelpful] snippet.

Comment: "Code can't really be supplied as the code base is 5 headers in size"  Then cut down the code to the **smallest** example that reproduces the problem.  (Sometimes this will reveal the underlying problem, also, so please create the smallest snippet that demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: At least it's not a Heisen-Bug as it is reproducible.

Comment: S. Lott. I am unsure precisely what causes the issue in the first place to know what segment to show. FileReader is called by a higher level class that supplies the file's Directory+Name, then CommentRemover removes the comments - CommentRemover is the part that catches the error.

Comment: char C; C = fgetc(Read); fgetc returns an int. Common mistake there, this might lead to wrong EOFs

Comment: Should implicitly convert, but good catch.

Comment: @Chris. The char C was purely as an intercept (to avoid using string that might corrupt it). Turning it to int, results in the same issue.

Comment: Ok, still you should change it, because even if this is not the error in your specifc testcase, it could be one later, where you will get EOFs at the wrong position. Experiened that problem just a few days ago ;) Anyways: When your loop terminates abnormally, is it because of the condition int he while statement or because of the break?

Comment: @Chris I changed it. Is there any way I can upload files? Not sure anyone could read my code though...

Comment: What is the source file? Is it a 'static' file on disk or have you just written to it? Has it been flushed to disk? Is it currently being written to? The printf's could be causing a cache flush (or giving enough time for one to occur) so that is why reading is variable. (just an idea).

Comment: @PAntoine The source file is a static file on disk. It works like a config file in that it's only meant to be read by the program, and edited by the user via some text editor.

Comment: have you tried `if (fread(&c,1,1,Read) == 0) break;` just in case there is a problem with the EOF at the end of the file? (I can't remember of the EOF marker is required for == EOF to work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some heap corruption going on. Without seeing code it's impossible to say.

Comment: And do you have any more information on heap corruption? If I am causing it, I'd certainly like to avoid it in future.

Comment: You have to check everything! Fill your code with asserts, such as assert that you're not writing to NULL pointers, that you're not writing too much data to a buffer, etc etc.

Answer (score 5):

This is the oldest error in the book, kind of.

You can't use a variable of type `char` to read characters (!), since the `EOF` constant doesn't fit.

You need:

```
int C;
```

Also, the `while` condition looks scary, you are incrementing `X` in the loop, then checking the (new) position, is that properly initialized? You don't show how `Copy.Array` is set up before starting the loop.

I would suggest removing that altogether, it's very strange code.

In fact, I don't understand why you loop reading single characters at all, why not just use `fread()` to read as much as you need?

Comment: Surprisingly it works. Char is deemed signed on this compiler (-127 to 127). But again, the char C (which is an int C) is purely for observation - changing it to int still means the error exists.

Comment: @SightS2: Okay, so there's more errors. But you must change it, since (obviously) the EOF symbol and all 8-bit byte values cannot both be expressed in an 8-bit char, there must be a collision which is very bad news.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, unwind's answer is a valid point although I'm not sure whether it explains the issues you are seeing.

Secondly,

```
printf("%d %c\n",C,C); //Remove/add this as necessary
```

might be a problem.  The `%d` and `%c` format specifiers expect an int to be the parameter, you are only passing a char.  Depending on your compiler, this might mean that they are too small.

---

This is what I think the problem is:

How are you allocating Copy.Array?  Are you making sure all its elements are zeroed before you start?  If you malloc it (malloc just leaves whatever garbage was in the memory it returns) and an element just happens to contain `0xFF`, your loop will exit prematurely because your while condition tests Copy.Array[X] before you have placed a character in that location.

This is one of the few cases where I allow myself to put an assignment in a condition because the pattern

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(fileStream)) != EOF)
{
    doSomethingWithC(c);
}
```

is really common

---

**Edit**

Just read your "Additionally" comment.  I think it is highly likely you are overrunning your output buffer.  I think you should change your code to something like:

```
    int X = 0; int C = 0; int I = 0;
    while(X < arraySize && (C = fgetc(Read)) != EOF)
    {
        Copy.Array[X] = C;
        printf("%d %c\n", (int)C, (int)C);
        X++;
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Note that I am assuming that you have a variable called `arraySize` that is set to the number of characters you can write to the array without overrunning it.  Note also, I am not writing the EOF to your array.

Comment: Thank you. Copy.Array uses malloc. I thought that, however, Copy.Array isn't used in the example above (I used the int C to test it without Copy.Array) - and ergo can't be at fault. For some reason Printf itself is somehow... changing this, but I don't grasp how or why.

Comment: @SightS2: Copy.Array **is** used in your example.  Look at the bit of code after the while keyword.  Your loop condition is wrong.  Also, see my comment on your printf.

Comment: It's not used in any meaningful way though. I am concerned this has become a pedantic type-checking exercise rather than a meaningful resolution of the bug.

Comment: @SightS2: You don't think that testing an uninitialised variable for a loop condition is meaningful?  This is what you are doing.  When you come into that loop `Copy.Array[X]` is uninitialised.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your error but this code:

```
C = fgetc(Read);
Copy.Array[X] = C;
if(C == EOF){break;}
```

Means you are adding the `EOF` value into your array - I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that, especially as your array is presumably `char` and `EOF` is `int`, so you'll actually end up with some other value in there (which could mess up later loops etc).

Instead I suggest you change the order so `C` is only put in the array once you know it is not `EOF`:

```
C = fgetc(Read);
if(C == EOF){break;}
Copy.Array[X] = C;
```

Comment: The EOF is used so that a function can search for it and replace it with a NULL. By default, a NULL is appended to the end of the amount of read characters, but for all intents the data is treated like a string/filestream hybrid.

Comment: @SightS2: If `Array` is an array of `char` then searching through it for `EOF` will never succeed - and neither will your loop condition - because `EOF` is an `int` constant outside the range of `char` as @unwind rightly says.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this isn't what I'd call a 'complete' answer (as the bug remains), this does solve the 'observer effect' element: I found, for some reason, printf was somehow 'fixing' the code, and using std::cout seemed to (well, I can't say 'fix' the problem) prevent the observer effect happening. That is to say, use std::cout instead of printf (as printf is the origin of the observer effect).

It seems to me that printf does something in memory on a lower level that seems to partially correct what does indeed seem to be a memory allocation error.